# What is example of a category not embeddable in category of sets?

Tags: category-theory, functors

What is example of a category $\mathcal{C}$ that cannot be embedded in Set (where by embedding I mean e.g. functor $\mathcal{C} \to Set$ injective on objects and morphisms)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category#Counter-examples

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00303